# Does onload function works correctly in IE10?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I have a page which contains multiple forms. I am calling a function localize() like`<body onload = 'localize()'>`.

Inside localize() function when I am using `aForms[0] = document.getElementById('form1');`
(aForms is an array to store all the form elements).

For the first form it works,but for subsequent forms it is getting null values in IE10.
This page was working fine with IE8 and IE9.

Forgot to mention my page is inside a frame.

Please help.

Comment: Do your forms have different IDs ? Why dont you use document.forms, it returns array of all the forms inside the document

Comment: Yes all the forms having different ids.

Comment: There might be something wrong with the univers but probably not

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/04/25/maybe-there-s-something-wrong-with-the-universe-but-probably-not.aspx

Comment: @RuneFS Well, yes, but in IE's case, it's historically the universe that's wrong...

Comment: @MattGibson yes but it's not the historic versions of IE in use here. It's more likely that the code worked in the older versions despite/because of the universe being at err

Answer (score 2):

It's best to separate your JavaScript from your HTML. Also, you should execute JavaScript at the end of the `<body>` because your page will load quicker. If it's in the `<head>`, you'll need to load the entire script before actually seeing your website.

So setup your HTML something like this:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Your Title</title>
    <head>
<body>
    <div></div>
    <!-- Your site here -->
    <script src="myJavaScript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then in your JavaScript file, listen in on the onload event:

```
window.onload = function () {
    // Use document.forms unless you need specific ones
    var forms = [
        document.getElementById('form1'),
        document.getElementById('form2')
    ];
    console.log(forms[0]);
    console.log(forms[1]); // Not null
};
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/C7mh2 for demo

Comment: Forgot to mention my page inside a frame.

Comment: How's this? http://jsfiddle.net/C7mh2/2 The key is this part iframe.contentWindow.document, which gives access to the IFrame's document object so you can grab elements inside.

Comment: I don't know why document.onload doesn't work. I had to change document to window.

Answer (score 0):

body `onload` works fine, May be you have some other issues with you code.
aForms[0] is a reference to your form, it not the array that will contain your all elements.

you have to use

```
aForms[0] = document.getElementById('form1')
var elements =aForms[0].getElementsByTagName('input');

// Now elements will contain all the input elements inside that aForm[0] i.e form1
  for (i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
    //some codes...
  }
```

You can use `document.forms` This returns collection of forms supported in almost all browsers. Here is an example

```
<body>
<form></form>
<form></form>
</body>

window.onload =function()
{
   var Forms = document.forms;
   for(var i=0;i<Forms.length;i++)
   {

       // Form[0] will contain reference to first form
       // You can use Form[i] to refer to respective form
       // If you want to check for id then following code may help you
       // Even you can check for name to by .name property

       if(Forms[0].id =='yourid')
       {
           // this is the form i want
       }
   }
}
```

If your form is contained within iframe and its in same domain

```
var Frames = document.getElementById( 'yourIframeId' );
var DOC = Frames.contentDocument || Frames.contentWindow.document;
var aForm = DOC.getElementById( 'form1');
```

Comment: Forgot to mention my page is inside an frame.

Comment: @DeepakKumarPadhy ok is it in same domain ?

Comment: Yes , its in the same domain.